# Nextjs app router Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'CacheStorage': Unexpected internal error

Tags: javascript, next.js, app-router

I'm using Next.js V13+ app router and I came across this DOM error. `open` is a state variable in one of the client components used to conditionally render JSX. I'm still not sure why this error would show up.